# Hints on using Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Verify Cauchy theorem for the function $z^3-iz^2-5z+2i$ if $C$ is the circle $\vert{z-2}\vert=2$. I have not come across any examples which use Cauchy theorem directly. So, any hints or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $w=z+2$ then 
$$\int_{|z-2|=2}(z^3-iz^2-5z+2i)dz=\int_{|w|=2}P(w)dw$$
for some third degree polynomial $P(w)=a_3w^3+a_2w^2+a_1w+a_0$.
Then use linearity and show that for $n=0,1,2,3,$ 
$$\int_{|w|=2}w^n dw=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi }(2e^{it})^n\cdot (2e^{it} dt)=0$$
where $w=2e^{it}$ and $dw=2e^{it} dt$
.

Answer (score 1):

The given function is a polynomial and so is entire. Cauchy's theorem then says that the integral over any circle is $0$.

If you want to verify this by direct computation, at least use linearity and compute the integral of its monomials instead of the complete polynomial.

You'll need to parametrize the circle: $\gamma(t) = 2+2(\cos t,\sin t)$.

Comment: Can you give me some idea on how to use linearity?

Comment: @AyanShah,$\int (z^3-iz^2-5z+2i) dz = \int z^3 dz -i \int z^2 dz -5 \int z dz+2i \int 1 dz$.

Comment: @what if C is the ellipse Iz-3iI+lz+3il=20?

Comment: @AyanShah, same thing, different parametrization.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$

The function becomes
$$f(x,y)=\left(x^3-3 x y^2+2 x y-5 x\right)+i \left(3 x^2 y-x^2-y^3+y^2-5 y+2\right)$$
define
$$u(x,y)=x^3-3 x y^2+2 x y-5 x;\;v(x,y)=3 x^2 y-x^2-y^3+y^2-5 y+2$$
The required integral can be written as
$$\oint_C {f\left( z \right)} \;dz = \oint_C {\left( {\;u\;dx - v\;dy} \right)}  + i\oint_C {\left( {\;v\;dx + u\;dy} \right)} $$
Using Green's theorem these real line integrals become double integrals
$$\oint_C {f\left( z \right)} \;dz = \iint\limits_D {\left( { - {v_x} - {u_y}} \right)}\;dxdy + i\iint\limits_D {\left( {{u_x} - {v_y}} \right)}\;dxdy$$
Both integrands are zero due to the Cauchy-Riemann relations. Indeed
$$\oint_C {f\left( z \right)} \;dz = \iint\limits_D {\left( {2x - 6xy - 2x + 6xy} \right)}\;dxdy + i\iint\limits_D {\left( { - 5 + 3{x^2} + 2y - 3{y^2} - \left( { - 5 + 3{x^2} + 2y - 3{y^2}} \right)} \right)}\;dxdy=0$$
as predicted by Cauchy theorem

Hope it helps

Comment: Interesting use of Green's theorem. +1

Comment: @Raffaele But did u use the condition?

Comment: @AyanShah Of course! I followed the proof of the Cauchy theorem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem#Proof